# siunitx overfull hbox dependent on table-format

Tags: tables, boxes, siunitx, warnings, texniccenter

There are a few similar questions (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57884/siunitx-overfull-hbox-warnings-when-including-significance-stars) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130238/warning-overfull-hbox-in-table)) regarding overfull `\hboxes` in `siunitx` tables but neither solves/explains the following. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!]%
\centering%
\sisetup{detect-none, mode=math, table-format=+1.1, table-auto-round}%
\begin{tabular}{ls[table-alignment=left]SSSS}%
\toprule%
A & \newton & 0.32 & 3.8 & -4.5 & -0.6 \\%
B & \newton & -0.12 & 1.1 & -1.6 & -1.0 \\%
C & \milli\metre & -2.45 & -7.0 & 2.3 & -4.3 \\%
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

When compiled with pdfLaTeX, overfull `\hbox` statements are present in the log file (these statements however are not picked up/flagged by `TeXniCenter` as warnings).

When the `table-format` option is altered to `table-format=+2.1` the warnings are still present but when `table-format=+3.1` the warnings suddenly disappear from the log file.

I have two questions:

1. Why does `table-format=+1.1` or `+2.1` produce overfull `\hbox` messages in the log file but not `table-format=+3.1`? Have I misunderstood something obvious in the `siunitx` [documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)?
2. Why are the pdfLaTeX warnings not raised as LaTeX warnings? Is this something specific to TeXnicCenter or a more general behaviour?

Comment: Use `table-format=-1.1` and the warnings disappear.

Comment: So they do, which is a bit strange. Also, if I change every minus sign to a plus sign the warnings also disappear (with `table-format=+1.1`) but if I have just _one_ minus sign I get a single warning. Perhaps it is a bug in `siunitx`?

Comment: One of your columns has two digits after the `.`, so you need something like `-1.2`.

Comment: Even with `table-auto-round`? In reality the data in the table comes from a separate file and has many more decimal places than what I want shown in the final table. I like the convenience of being able to round the numbers off at the LaTeX-end rather than have to modify other data processing code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `table-format` key is used to set up how much space `siunitx` reserves in a table column for numbers. As such, it should reserve enough space for the largest entry in that column. The format is the same as a number, and the input is processed by the same code. As such, if you need to reserve space for a sign then using `-` rather than `+` is recommended as with standard settings `+` will be 'thrown away' during parsing. Thus `+1.1` will (probably) only reserve space for one digit before and one digit after the decimal marker, with none for the sign.

You will see the warnings disappear if you allow enough space, even if it's the 'wrong kind'. Thus something like `-2.1` will reserve (in most cases) the same space as `+3.1`, as the entra 'digit' and the sign are the same width. Thus over-specifying digits may well remove warnings, but at the cost of loosing proper control of what is really going on.

The overfull box warnings will be in the log and come from TeX, not LaTeX. How they are then presented depends on the editor you use.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Joseph. Is it stated anywhere in the documentation (which is excellent btw) that a `-` sign should be used to reserve space rather than a `+` sign? Most examples seem to use a `+` sign.

Comment: @luke Possibly I need to tighten that up in the docs, or perhaps alter the behaviour (which is more an accident of implementation than any deliberate plan!).

Comment: No worries Joseph. With this question and answer now on stackexchange others should have no problems.